# Remover palavras repetidas usando python

Tags: python, arquivo, python-2.7, texto

Estou com um arquivo texto com muitas palavras repetidas. Preciso que cada palavra no arquivo apareça apenas uma vez.

```
 import  codecs

 wordList = codecs.open('Arquivo.txt' , 'r')
 wordList2 = codecs.open('Arquivo2.txt', 'w')

 for x in range(len(wordList)) :
    for y in range(x + 1, len(wordList ) ):
        if wordList[x] == wordList[y]:
            wordList2.append(wordList[x] )
        for y in wordList2:
             wordList.remove(y)
```

**Erro apresentado**

```
     for x in range(len(wordList)):
 TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()
```

Comment: Qual a dificuldade em concreto que está a encontrar?

Comment: A parte da iteração entre as palavras não estou conseguindo resolver.

Comment: Da uma olhada na minha resposta, para fazer `len(wordList)` é preciso que `wordList` seja uma lista, e da forma que vc fez ainda é um `_io.TextIOWrapper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de abrir os arquivos assim:

```
wordList = codecs.open('Arquivo.txt' , 'r')
wordList2 = codecs.open('Arquivo2.txt', 'w')
```

Tente assim:

```
wordList = codecs.open('Arquivo.txt' , 'r').readlines()
wordList2 = codecs.open('Arquivo2.txt', 'w')
```

Recomendo que tb dê uma lida no [guia de estilo de codificação python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
O uso de CamelCase para nomes de variáveis, não é recomendado no python.

Comment: Como converter o wordList em lista? Não posso tentar passar direto no arquivo? 
Fazendo essa mudança deu um erro:    ' IOError: File not open for reading '

Comment: Desculpe, cometi um erro na resposta (já corrigi), a segunda abertura é para escrita então não tem o `readlines`. Depois que vc abre o arquivo para leitura vc precisa ler o conteudo dele, na minha resposta estou fazendo exatamente isso com readlines. Diretamente no arquivo vc só pode fazer operações de leitura/escrita.

Comment: Dúvida: `word_list = set(codecs.open("arquivo.txt", "r"))` não seria suficiente para eliminar as linhas repetidas? Nunca trabalhei com a `codecs` e não sei se o comportamento seria análogo ao `open` nativo.

Comment: Utilizo o codecs pois com o open estava dando erro para ler o arquivo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, tb nunca trabalhei com codecs, vc falou em linhas repetidas, ele fala em **palavras** repetidas, de qualquer forma foquei no que ele chamou de **erro apresentado** na questão.

Comment: @RivaldoHater minha correção resolveu?

Comment: Estou aplicando as alterações

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Agora tenho que ajeitar minhas interação que estar dando erro. Obrigado