# Como abrir um arquivo txt e usar para imprimir oque eu quero

Tags: python

fiz o seguinte codigo:

```
def caixaAlta(texto):
    return texto.upper()

def ultimosNomes(nomeInteiro):
    lista = nomeInteiro.split(' ')
    if lista[-1].lower() == 'junior' or lista[-1].lower()=='sobrinho' \
       or lista[-1].lower()=='neto' or lista[-1].lower()=='filho':
        return caixaAlta(lista[-2])+" "+caixaAlta(lista[-1])
    else:
        return caixaAlta(lista[-1])

def primeirosNomes(nomeInteiro):
    lista = nomeInteiro.split(' ')
    nome=''
    if lista[-1].lower() == 'junior' or lista[-1].lower()=='sobrinho' \
     or lista[-1].lower()=='neto' or lista[-1].lower()=='filho':
        for i in range(len(lista)-2):
            nome = nome + inicial(lista[i])
    else:
        for i in range(len(lista)-1):
            nome = nome + inicial(lista[i])
    return nome

def inicial(nome):
    for i in nome:
        if nome=='da' or nome=='do' or nome=='de' \
           or nome=='das' or nome=='dos' or nome=='e':
            nome=nome.replace(i,".d")
            return nome.lower()+' '

        else:
            return nome[0].upper()

def referencia(nomeInteiro):
    return ultimosNomes(nomeInteiro)+','+primeirosNomes(nomeInteiro)


print(referencia(input('Digite nome do autor: ')))
```

a saida dele vai ser a seguinte:

```
> Digite nome do autor: Joao Joca da Silva  <- o nome eu digito
> SILVA,JJ.da <- isso que imprime
```

Desse jeito que fiz eu crio nomes e ele imprime do jeito que eu quero, mas como faço para usar apenas nomes de um arquivo txt e ele imprimir dessa mesma forma?

Comment: A questão não será mais de como ler um arquivo de texto em python linha a linha ? Eu questiono isto porque a pergunta tem muito código mas não parece de todo estar relacionado com a sua duvida.

Comment: É que do jeito que eu fiz eu teria que perguntar no próprio programa um nome para abreviar. O que estou perguntando em vez de eu colocar esse nome, eu pegar os nomes de um arquivo txt. Desculpa se não conseguir deixa claro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente Assim:

Crie um arquivo chamado arquivo.txt com os nomes que vc deseja, então faça:

```
import  codecs
wordList = codecs.open('Arquivo.txt' , 'r').readlines()
for w in wordlist:
    print(referencia(w[:-1]))
```

> Pythonismo:

Praticamente todas as linguagens tem convenções e o python não é diferente, seria interessante que vc desse uma lida no [guia de estilo de codificação python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), para citar um exemplo, ao invés de utilizar camelcase (`minhaVariavel`), utilize snakecase (`minha_variavel`)

Em python vc não precisa daquele monte de ifs para ver se algo esta em uma lista, na primeira sequencia de ifs do seu codigo, ao inves de fazer:

```
if lista[-1].lower() == 'junior' or lista[-1].lower()=='sobrinho' \
   or lista[-1].lower()=='neto' or lista[-1].lower()=='filho':
    return caixaAlta(lista[-2])+" "+caixaAlta(lista[-1])
else:
    return caixaAlta(lista[-1])
```

Voce pode fazer

```
if lista[-1].lower() in ['junior', 'sobrinho', 'neto', 'filho']
```

Veja que vc pode tambem ler essa lista de um arquivo texto, da mesma forma que foi feito para ler o arquivo de input dos nomes.

**Observação.**
 
Essa é apenas uma forma de ler um arquivo txt em python, escolhi aleatoriamente (pq ja tinha respondido algo com codecs) mas ha outras formas de fazer isso.

Para complementar, veja tb [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235188/7412), aqui no STOpt.

Comment: mano muito obrigado porem o resultado saiu um de baixo do outro, teria alguma forma deles sair os nomes linha por linha?

Comment: É só retirar o `\n` do final das words em wordlist, vou editar, veja q vou fazer uma alteração na ultima linha do primeiro fragamento de codigo

Comment: Veja se 'funfa' agora.

Comment: Deu certo mano muito obrigado!